# PHP and MySQL Countdown and update DB in every second and at expiration save results in DB

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a countdown.In my educational website,the user has two hours to make a laboratory.

1. I want to display PHP dynamically countdown like (02:00:00) after 1 second (01:59:59),etc. I found only JQuery Countdown (with time expiration action) but it doesn't agree point 2.
2. In every second,I have to update table (ex: time_remaining  field) with countdown value. Why this ? There are situations when an user/student solve some equations and the Internet connection is broken or the computer is shutting down unexpected, so the student could reload page but from last state countdown. Or, the student could make a pause and replay the laboratory when he wants.
3. After time expiration, I want to save results in database (I think,here is simple)

Can you help me with first 2 points ? Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you update `time_remaining` if you can have something like `time_start` and `time_expiry`?

When your user starts the lab exercise, simply create the session associated with that user, mark the current date and give it expiry time. It's bad design to rely on client side to update a database table so you can be sure no one is cheating. Better make it safe from the ground up.

Have the countdown clock just as convenience for the user, it shouldn't be something that your app relies on.

As for saving the data into the database - since you're using a form, you can simply trigger submit event when countdown reaches zero. Code is trivial:

```
$("#yourSubmitForm").trigger('submit');
```

It'll act as if a person submitted it by clicking the button or whatever mechanism you implemented.

Comment: because the user could meet broken internet connection or other.with that last time stored in database,the user can make laboratory starting at last state time.